# Calculating area of pixels in continuous raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, area

I have a raster with continuous values between 0 and 1.

I want to calculate the area (can be a number of pixels too) in this raster which has values in the specific range - say between 0.1 and 0.2 and 0.3-0.4.

In other words, the goal is to see which interval occupies the larger area.

What tool could be used for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the counting by

1. using the [ReClassify function in Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to re-classify your raster into an integer raster in which pixel values in your ranges `[0.1, 0.2), [0.3, 0.4) ...` are mapped to new integer values, e.g. `1, 2, ...`,
2. [building a Value/Raster Attribute Tables (VAT/RAT)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm) for the new integer raster. In the VAT, there should be a `COUNT` field telling you the number of `1`-pixels, `2`-pixels etc., which correspond to the number of pixels whose value are in your ranges `[0.1, 0.2), [0.3, 0.4)` etc., respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Without creating new raster (reclassify) You can change raster symbology with given intervals. Then you can just read how many cells are in each class.

Comment: I know how to change raster symbology but not sure what tool can I use to count/read the number of cells in each class?

Comment: Next to each interval in symbology should be number of cells within that class

Answer (score 0):

Why not just calculate the area directly in the attribute table?

1. Use the raster calculator to isolate the range of values you're interested in
2. Convert your raster to polygon
3. Use the dissolve tool to create one feature
4. Create a new column in the attribute table titled "area", and then use calculate geometry.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post/question but still seems relevant. If I understand the question correctly, this can be easily done using the Cell Statistics tool within the Imagery Analyst tool set.

```
out_raster = arcpy.ia.CellStatistics("NameOfyourInputRaster", "SUM", "DATA", "SINGLE_BAND", 90, "AUTO_DETECT"); out_raster.save(r"C:\Users\PathtoYourOutput.gdb\NameOfyourOutputRaster")
```